# Problema al concatenar strings con variables

Tags: javascript, concatenación

javascript no me reconoce el concatenar strings con variables usando "${variable}", me lo toma como un string mas. Saben cual es el problema? Les dejo un ejemplo.

```
const prueba = "tardes";
const saludo = "buenas ${prueba}";
```

Comment: Si quieres concatenar string y variables, debes usar las comillas inclinadas ``

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, no me había dado cuenta de que influía el tipo de comilla.

Comment: Como ha mencionado el compañero, lo correcto sería usar [plantillas literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás usando comillas cuando en realidad deberías utilizar el caracter de tilde invertida (``):

```
const saludo = `buenas ${prueba}`;
```